# Text scaling in header

Tags: html, css, text, scaling

I'm making a site and I'd like it to scale properly on all devices.

On my 1080x1920 screen, it works perfectly, but on thinner devices the page does not look very good.

[image]

[image]

The white space is where the header text should be.
My code can be found here:

```
.header {
height: 80px;
background-color:#00117D;
background-size:100%;
color:#FFF;
font-size:30px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height: 80px;
padding: 0 30px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color:#FFF;
font-family:"Segoe UI";
}

.header p, .header a {
float: left;
margin: 0;
margin-left:30px;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

https://github.com/MooneyDev/project-Mooney

Comment: You might want to consider posting some code here rather than linking to external links for a better chance to get the response you need

Comment: I've posted some code.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in previous projects it used em font size values on all properties but the body, and then used [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) at various stages to change the px based body value as required.  This should catch all other values and keep them proportionate.

I would suggest you look into using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as it should really speed things up and take away a lot of the pain involved in responsive dev.

Comment: I would use bootstrap, however, I really wanted to make this my own.

Comment: In that case, download and look through the bootstrap code base.  It will be really informative and give you a good understanding of what to do and why.  Essentially, you need a series of classes, manipulated in media queries and for ease utilising some sort of grid system

Comment: So Id use a @media rule for handheld devices that scaled  the header?

Comment: @Mooney Indeed.  You can use max and min. Min kicks in as a minium of that specified dimensions, while max stops working above the specified dimensions eg. @ media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ /* New rules here */ }